# Emacs freezes - Profiler shows three dots

Tags: performance, exwm, profiler

Recently emacs freezes for multiple seconds, while process `emacs --daemon -f exwm enable` CPU usage goes up to 100%. I tried `--debug-init` instead of `--daemon` but still remain in the dark about the three dots in the profiler report:

```
    5802  74% + timer-event-handler
     862  11% + redisplay_internal (C function)
     735   9% + ...
     227   2% + evil-escape-pre-command-hook
      48   0% + command-execute
      26   0% + evil-repeat-pre-hook
      23   0% + evil-repeat-post-hook
      20   0% + company-post-command
      15   0% + winner-save-old-configurations
       6   0% + evil--jump-handle-buffer-crossing
       5   0%   global-hl-line-highlight
       3   0% + which-key--hide-popup
       2   0% + undo-auto--add-boundary
       2   0% + direnv--maybe-update-environment
       2   0% + jit-lock--antiblink-post-command
```

Answer (score 1):

It’s complicated and undocumented, but it is a collection of nodes in the tree where the exact correct parent node is unknown. It’s a small portion of your profile, so you can probably just ignore it. Figure out what is going on with those timer events instead.